# A basic error using loops and functions in C

Tags: c

For some reason my code will consistently print out zeros.

I was supposed to make a code in which I enter three numbers,

1. The first number
2. The ratio
3. The amount of numbers to be displayed

The code should display those numbers.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void forloop(int firstNum,int ratio,int repeats);
int main(void)
{ 
    int firstNum = 0;
    int ratio = 0;
    int repeats = 0;
    printf("First number of the series: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstNum);
    printf("the ratio of the series: ");
    scanf("%d", &ratio);
    printf("the amount of numbers to display is ");
    scanf("%d", &repeats);
    forloop(firstNum,ratio,repeats);
}


void forloop(int firstNum,int ratio,int repeats)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=1; i!=repeats+1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", firstNum*(pow( ratio, i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: `pow()` returns a `double`, so the expression in the `printf()` statement has type `double`, but you attempt to print it using the format `%d` which expects an `int`.  You need to use `%f` (or `%e` or `%g`) instead.  Also consider using an idiomatic `for` loop in your `forloop()` function: `for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)` and reference `i+1` in the expression.

Comment: To save time, enable all compiler warnings.  A good compiler will advise about `printf("%d ", firstNum*(pow( ratio, i)));`

Comment: [Compiler warnings](https://ideone.com/VAdUbZ). Enable them, read them, love them.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the issue with printing zeros:

```
void forloop(int firstNum,int ratio,int repeats)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=1; i!=repeats+1;i++)
    {
        printf("%.0f ", firstNum*(pow((double)ratio,(double)i)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JonathanLeffler in the comments, you have a bug. The line

```
printf("%d ", firstNum*(pow( ratio, i)));
```

is wrong because `pow` returns a double but in the printf specifications `%d` expects an integer.
So, you can either change the specifier in your printf to a floating point one, i.e., `%f, %g, %e, %F, %G, %E` et cetera or cast pow's output to int by doing `(int)pow(ratio, i)`.

In the first case, as @JadMrad said, if you are printing a double and you don't want to have decimal numbers, you can specify the number of digits at the right of the decimal point using `"%.Nf"` instead of `"%f"` where N is the number of decimal points that you want.

Nevertheless, in your case it seems to me that you are expecting always integer numbers. Then,

```
printf("%d ", firstNum*((int)pow( ratio, i)));
```

sounds like a better solution to me.